# How to define a git-bash alias for create models in Models folder on laravel?

Tags: laravel, git-bash

I want to make a model in a specific folder with an alias command that gets only the model name. I mean I want to define a alias git-bash that make for me the model in Models folder in App\Models. Look at following command:

```sh
makemodel User -m
```

that then runs this command:

```sh
php artisan make:model Models/User -m
```

Comment: You can create own command to create a Model in specific directory or much more, read this article https://medium.com/@imfx/create-make-custom-commands-in-laravel-9fa002da582e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bash file `makemodel`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get the first parameter
$MODEL=$1

php artisan make:model Models/$MODEL -m
```

Now just call it with `./makemodel User`

Not sure if you want the `-m` to be optional, but if you do you could pass it with some extra code.